# Next.js always fail at downloading fonts from Google Fonts

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, google-fonts

I've created a new Next.js project for the first time using `create-next-app`, and I've successfully run it with `npm run dev`.

The problem is that everytime Next.js starts, it says:

```
FetchError: request to https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/inter/v12/UcC73FwrK3iLTeHuS_fvQtMwCp50KnMa1ZL7W0Q5nw.woff2 failed, reason: 
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\Desktop\documents\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\node-fetch\index.js:1:65756)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:511:28)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:495:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:511:28)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  type: 'system',
  errno: 'ENETUNREACH',
  code: 'ENETUNREACH'
}
- error Failed to download `Inter` from Google Fonts. Using fallback font instead.
```

My goal is to make Next.js use the actual font not the fallback one.

I don't know why this happens as I didn't change anything in Next.js yet. Even opening the URL `https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/inter/v12/UcC73FwrK3iLTeHuS_fvQtMwCp50KnMa1ZL7W0Q5nw.woff2` in my browser works well so I guess it's not a networking issue.

I tried to search in [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/docs) documentation and I didn't find any duplicates here.

Here's `layout.tsx` that's located inside `src/app/`:

```tsx
import './globals.css'
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })

export const metadata = {
  title: 'Create Next App',
  description: 'Generated by create next app',
}

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>{children}</body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

Also, I'm running Node version `20.3.0` and npm version `9.4.1` with Next.js `13.4`. Basically the latest at the time of writing this question.

Comment: It works on my end this is the demo that nextjs provides. Maybe try different browser?

Comment: Try clearing the cache. Also try using a vpn. Might be a network issue as it works fine on my end as well.

Comment: @user16967562 I've tried different browsers and still same issue. It uses the [fallback font](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzKlN.png) everytime.  *`.__className_f6fa1f` is the `body`*.

Comment: @MoinulHaq Still clearing the cache and using different browsers doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: @kevin-m-mansour The error code is for network error. Can try a vpn as sometimes dns can cause issues like this. VPN > Clear next Cache > Try

Comment: @MoinulHaq It's not a caching problem, see my answer.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Trying different browsers and clearing the cache didn't help either. I've solved it by adding key [`display: 'swap'`](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/components/font#display), where value [`swap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/font-display) means:

> Gives the font face an extremely small block period and an infinite swap period.

Where font "block" period means:

> If the font face is not loaded, any element attempting to use it must render an invisible fallback font face. If the font face successfully loads during this period, it is used normally.

And font "swap" period means:

> If the font face is not loaded, any element attempting to use it must render a fallback font face. If the font face successfully loads during this period, it is used normally.

And that's pretty much what I was looking for.

I've also added key [`adjustFontFallback: false`](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/components/font#adjustfontfallback) which means:

> A boolean value that sets whether an automatic fallback font should be used to reduce [Cumulative Layout Shift](https://web.dev/cls/). The default is `true`.

So here's my final `layout.tsx`:

```tsx
import './globals.css'
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'], display: 'swap', adjustFontFallback: false})


export const metadata = {
  title: 'Create Next App',
  description: 'Generated by create next app',
}

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>{children}</body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this sound a bit placebo though? The error you showed on the OP says you have a `ENETUNREACH` network error which suggests that your machine does not have support for IPv4 or IPv6 and is trying to connect to an address of that type. I mean, are the fonts you chose actually the ones displayed on the page?

Comment: nextjs documentation says `swap` is the default value for the `display` property. https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/components/font#display

Comment: I'm facing the same bug and this doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

Same issue with Bricolage Grotesque, resolved with the following:

```js
export const secondaryFont = Bricolage_Grotesque({
    subsets: ["latin"],
    variable: "--font-grotesque",
    display: "swap",
    adjustFontFallback: false,
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For my case, the fonts were loading correctly in the production environment where I have the SSL installed.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue, fixed simply by adding `display:"swap"`

```
import { Poppins } from "next/font/google";

const poppins = Poppins({
  weight: ["300", "400", "500"],
  subsets: ["latin"],
  display: "swap",
});

<body className={`${poppins.className} ...`}> 
...
</body>
```

Comment: Like https://stackoverflow.com/a/76484168/4957508 did?